# What is the recommended application layer to use in 3 tier architecture using Java?

Tags: java, android, mysql, architecture

So my situation is that I am trying to figure out the best architecture for my system to use, current my project consists of a frontend using the Android SDK, and a MySQL database what I need my application layer to do is make requests to and from a REST api, and to manage a login system with the database.

I've been told that Apache tomcat with a java servlet might be a good approach but I'd like to ask here to see if you guys have any ideas.

Comment: You could save a ton of developing time if you use a BaaS such as Parse.com. They have nice API's to handle rest calls, local datastore to persist on device and a flexible mongoDB online. And the API's were recently open sourced so you can look under the hood if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll take a look into this and see what I can find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on your requirement. For not so complicated business logic , tomcat which is only a web server may suffice. However , if you have complex business logic , distributed architecture , clustering etc. which may need to support EJB, JMS etc then tomcat will not be sufficient but you will need app server like JBoss , Weblogic etc.

Comment: It's not an overly complex program, I just need to return data to my front end so that I can display it in the GUI, and be able to set and compare login details, to and from the MySQL database. Do you think that Tomcat would fit with this role?

Comment: Yes , for this requirement you should go for tomcat. Don't make stuff complex for simple requirements .